# android: Shared Preferences only for active session (until it will be destroyed)

Tags: android

I've a music service which is steering my music with a checkbox. The checkbox states will be saved in my shared preferences correctly! Basic config = music at app start ON and checkbox ON too. So long all works fine!

I want to save these states **ONLY in the active app session**. After restarting my app, it should be the basic state (music and checkbox ON). In this code he starts with this state which was the last one.

Thx for ur help!

**Java Code:**

```
    chkBoxMusic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMusic);

    boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
    chkBoxMusic.setChecked(isChecked);

    chkBoxMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonview, boolean isChecked) {

    Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
    ActivitySound.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");

       if (!isChecked) {

          stopService(new Intent(ActivitySound.this, MusicService.class));
       }

       else {

          startService(new Intent(ActivitySound.this, MusicService.class));
       }

      }

       });

   }

    public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();        
}

    public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);

    return isChecked;       

}
```

Comment: When you say "the active app session", do you mean, "until the app is hidden by another app", or, "until this app is killed by the OS", or, "until the phone is power cycled", or ...?

Comment: i mean if the app is finished u get back to the app desktop. I need this shared preferences only for the time i'm IN the app. When app is closed and i restart it, then it should have the basic settings. thx for help!

Comment: When an app is minimised, perhaps by pressing the <home> button, it keeps running. The top `Activity` enters the `onStop()` state. When you run it again by hitting the launcher icon, the top Activity is cycled round through the `onStart()` state. But it keeps running the whole time. Do you want the preferences reset when that happens? How many different `Activity`s make up your app? Is rotation enabled? What about when your app is running and someone powers the phone down, should the reset happen then?

Comment: no i dont mean going back for example to the home button. i mean if the app is closed. imagine u start a game and if u have finished playing u geht back to the app icons/desktop. my code above shows that im using a service for background music and im using shared preferences for saving the checkbox state. All i want is that the shared preferences works only if the app is ACTIVE, i mean so long the app is running. when im unchecking my checkbox state and close the app, at next start the checkbox is also unchecked..but it should be checked=true..thats the basic state.

Answer (score 1):

To remove *all* shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

But exactly when to do that is still under negotiation - see comments above! It's not entirely clear what you want even now. You could try putting this in the `onStop` method of your Activity and seeing if that gives the results you want.

Comment: You did change it to work with your own preference file? I edited the answer. Sorry, I thought it was clear.

Comment: i've changed it like ur edited version minutes before but it doesnt work. when i restart my app, the checkbox state is saved from the preferences and not the basic state :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20955/discussion-between-emrys57-and-synthesis)

Comment: emrys sry but u talked bullshit, it has nothing to do with the lifecycle, onStart(), onStop() and so on. you didnt ve understand my problem but its really clear described. And u ve never read my code clearly. why are u answering to that problem if u dont have any idea??